# R: underscore letters in forest plot of meta-analysis using the metafor package

Tags: r, plot, data-visualization

Is there a way to present symbols (e.g. greek letters, symbols or underscore/upperscore letters) as labels in a forest plot of an `rma()` object generated by the `forest()` function of the metafor package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a nonsense example but it hopefully illustrates the underlying idea:

```
library(metafor)
data(dat.bcg)

labs <- paste(dat.bcg$author, dat.bcg$year)
## Replace the first label with a greek letter, a superscript and a subscript
labs[1] <- expression(beta[123]^123)

res <- rma(ai=tpos, bi=tneg, ci=cpos, di=cneg, data=dat.bcg, measure="RR", 
           method="REML")
forest(res, slab = labs)
```

[image]

Comment: Interesting! I have never actually tried this out, but I am glad to see that this works.

Comment: I can't get the same to work when setting custom mlab using: label <- expression(tau^2), and then setting mlab = label in the forest call arguments. Any tips @Wolfgang?

Comment: `label <- expression(tau^2); forest(res, mlab=label)` works for me.